# Render a component in jsx if a certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

Really new to react, I have this part of navigation in my Navbar.js using `react-router-dom` useLocation hook, I am able to get the active path I have to views and I want to render custom text when a user arrives at the view with `JSX` something like

```
if(path==="login" || path==="signin"){
  `<h1>welcome</h1> ${userName}!` 
}
```

How can I check if condition A or B is met then render the appropriate text using `jsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator for conditional rendering in `JSX` like

```
{path==="login" || path==="signin" ? <> <h1>welcome</h1> {userName} </> : null}
```

Simple :-)

Comment: Wrap `<h1>welcome</h1> {userName}` in a fragment and it would work

Comment: Thanks I forget.

Comment: I prefer this as it's recommended not to use if statement in jsx.

Comment: @CynthiaOnyilimba Not recommented? Sorry, I might have missed something? I don't think this is correct.

Answer (score 5):

You must explicitly tell what to return, in your example you do not return anything. So, You can do either :

```
if (path === "login" || path === "signin") {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>welcome</h1> {userName}
    </>
  );
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Or use operator `&&` to conditionally render.

```
{
  (path === "login" || path === "signin") && (
    <>
      <h1>welcome</h1> {username}
    </>
  );
}
```

**Read more about conditional rendering** [[here]](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: You could also mention https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html, a list of pretty much every method to realize conditional rendering in react

Comment: Thanks, I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Return the value
- Use JSX and not a string
- Put everything in a container such as a React Fragment

Such:

```
if(path==="login" || path==="signin") {
    return <>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        {userName}!
    </>;
}
```

… but that logic should probably be handled by your routes rather than an `if` statement.